# HTML Form button in PHP While loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a while loop in PHP that selects data from a database

I want to have a complete button for each row returned which, when pressed will run an SQL Query to change the value of the `status` column of that particular row

my while loop is:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from messages where status = :status and (assigned_to = :assigned_to1 OR assigned_to = :assigned_to2) ");
$stmt->execute(array(':status' => '', ':assigned_to1' => $user_result["sequence"], ':assigned_to2' => ''));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$i=0;
if(count($records) > 0) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="7">You have '.count($records).' Messages</td>
    </tr>';
    foreach($records as $Messages) {
        $i++;
        echo '<tr>
        <td>'.AdminNameLookup($Messages["assigned_to"]).'</td>
        <td>'.$Messages["caller_company"].'</td>
        <td>'.$Messages["caller_telephone"].'</td>
        <td>'.$Messages["caller_email"].'</td>
        <td>'.$Messages["caller_message"].'</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="CompleteMessages['.$i.']" value="" /></td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

but I'm not too sure on how to handle the PHP on submit?

Comment: Try `array_keys($_POST['CompleteMessages'])[0]` (assuming PHP 5.4 or newer)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this instead:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="CompleteMessages" value="'.$i.'" /></td>
```

You can then get the id with:

```
$Id = $_POST['CompleteMessages'];
```

Personally I'd have `$i` set to `$Messages["message_id"]` to you can find what Id you have actually submitted.

You also need to wrap everything in a `form` tag:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before sending data you need to create html form tag. And also you have pass values using input tag values.

format tag should be like this below code.

```
 <form action="" method="">
 <input  type="" value="">
 <input type="submit" name="CompleteMessages['.$i.']" value="" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the value of the row where you clicked the submit button,
then you will need a unique key for each record.

Lets assume that the messages table has a MessageID column.

One approach would be to call a javascript function.

Let's say your javascript function was called UpdateColumn(ID,ColName,Index)

Here's what would need to be added to each input button (pseudocode)

```
onclick="UpdateColumn($Messages['MessageID'],'Status',$i)"
```

Then your javascript will need to lookup value from input CompleteMessages[Index]

The Javascript could call your request php via ajax ...

```
update.php?MessageID=MessageID&Column=Status&Value=CompleteMessages[Index].value
```

And finally your php which handles the submit would take the values

using

```
$MessageID=$_REQUEST["MessageID"];
$Column=$_REQUEST["Column"];
$Value=$_REQUEST["Value"];
```

Then you will want to run a sql query which updates your database accordingly.